# Angular 13: Delete request to api with some effects

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have an frontend app that I have connected to my backend it works well but when I delete the div with post it disappears unclear, I need to add some effects to it so I can see that the post really disappears in my eyes. I know it's not hard but I'm a newbie in Angular and this is my first frontend app

Delete Post Method:

```
deletePost1(id:number){
    this.messageService.delete(id).subscribe(res => {
      this.messages = this.messages.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      console.log('Post deleted successfully!');
    })
  }
```

delete post method from service:

```
delete(id: number) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.apiURL + 'api/message/' + id, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      )
  }
```

Comment: You could display some banner indicating that the resource was removed successfully. Or if you're looking for something flashier, popup notifications could be useful, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display a message using the ngx-toaster package

First install it using npm :

```
npm install ngx-toastr
```

Then add it to your app.module.ts

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      tapToDismiss: false,
      autoDismiss: true
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    ToastrService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your component create `deletePost()` like this :

```
constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }

deletePost1(id:number) {
    this.messageService.delete(id).subscribe(res => {
        this.messages = this.messages.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        this.toastr.success("Post deleted successfully!", 'success', { timeOut: 2500 });

    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but how can I add some styles to it, cause it displays text with small font-size and it displays on the left border of the web-page

Comment: There are many configurations you can add to it. Check it's npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr and the options section